# Binary Hamming Distance

Tags: c, recursion, hamming-distance

I have a problem about Hamming distance that writting a c program to enumerate all possible binary patterns which have length N and Hamming distance H to
the origin(must solve by using recursive).

Examples:

Input: (3,1)

Output: (001 , 010 , 100)

Input: (4,2)

Output: (0011 , 0101 , 0110 , 1001 , 1010 , 1100)

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hamming();

int main(void) {
    int n , h , time;
    scanf("%d", &time);
    while(time--) {
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &h);
        hamming(n,h);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void hamming(int n , int h) {
    if(n>h && h==0) {
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) printf("0");
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    if(n==h && h>0) {
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) printf("1");
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("0");
    hamming(n-1,h);
    printf("1");
    hamming(n-1,h-1);
}
```

The output of the code will miss some 0 or 1 unpredictable, I've been thinking about this question about 3 days. Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Why you tag with c++? There is nothing related to it!

Comment: This code does not compile, so it cannot produce any result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and please read "[ask]". -- If the Hamming distance is a value determined by _two_ values, how can you solve this task? Please elaborate a bit, show us some examples of input, actual output, and expected output (in part you did). And tell us at least in a nutshell about the algorithm you like to implement.

Comment: That `void hamming();` forward declaration shows exactly why I despise  unnecessary forward declarations. The real function is `void hamming(int n , int h);` ... Solve this by putting the whole function definition _above_ `main` and remove the erroneous forward declaration.